# SharedPreferences not reading Data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I'm saving two parts of data the users password and username to use at a later data and a random combination of letters to then check when the app is executed again to avoid the login screen again.

I had this working yesterday and for some reason, I expect I misplaced code when adding a feature and now cannot get it working again, I've tried all day to fix it and yet I cannot.

EDIT1: For some reason, it goes to the else statement on the "CheckPrefs" method, **which I CANNOT UNDERSTAND.**

EDIT2: It saves the preferences fine and goes to the intent but, it just can't read it.

Code:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPregs";
    public static final String PREFS_CHECK = "CheckSignedIn";
    public static final String UID ="";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CheckPrefs();

        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

    } 
    private void CheckPrefs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //checks to see if the user has signed in before if they have it gets there data from SharedPreferences and checks against our database via HttpPost.
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_CHECK, 0);
        String SCheck1 = settings.getString("key4", null);
        if (SCheck1 != null  && equals(UID)) {
            Intent c = new Intent(this, CheckUserInfo.class);
            startActivity(c);   

        } else {

        }



    }
    //create bracket.

    public void postLoginData() {

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

        try {
            // Add user name and password
            uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
            String username = uname.getText().toString();

            pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
            String password = pword.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences signedin = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_CHECK, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = signedin.edit();
            editor1.putString("key4", UID);
            editor1.commit();


            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("key1", username);
            editor.putString("key2", password);
            editor.commit();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();
            Log.w("HttpPost", str);

            if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                Log.w("HttpPost", "TRUE");
                result.setText("Login successful");
                try {Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent login = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class);
                startActivity(login);

            } else {
                Log.w("HttpPost", "FALSE");
                result.setText(str);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == ok) {

            postLoginData();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pword.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        // Click end
    }
    // if statement
}

// class ends here
```

Comment: if (SCheck1 != null  && equals(UID))? always make false

Comment: How? To me that seems like a correct statement.

Comment: Trying to get clarification. Correct me if I'm wrong: You want to pull key4 value from shared pref, if the value of key4 matches the constant UID, you want to go into your IF statement? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

need to see where you are saving your preferences, so we can match it up with how you're calling your preferences... but, is this a typo?

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPregs";
```

Should it be "MyPrefs" instead of "MyPregs"?

Comment: Yes, it is, I was going to change that once I fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
if (SCheck1 != null  && equals(UID))
```

but do you maybe mean to say

```
if (SCheck1 != null  && !SCheck.equals(UID))
```

?

Comment: No? I want to check if UID is in the shared preferences, not to check if it doesn't equal UID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'reverse comparison' pattern too:

```
if (UID.equals(SCheck1)) {

} else {

}
```

This way, you don't have to bother checking SCheck1 == null. UID.equals(null) will return false instead of null.equals(UID) throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: Nope, does the exact same thing.

Comment: Before you do the comparison, have you checked what the value of SCheck1 is? Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes, triple checked. I don't know what I did, I think I misplaced some code and now I can't find what I did, anywhere.

Comment: And what is that value? Is it empty like the UID?